# Unknown AVD Error in Android Studio Emulator, me too

Tags: android-studio

Also i have this problem, but with the guide on your site i can't fix, i'm using linux and i installed all sdk to emulate android but it does not work. I looked for solutions on the internet but they did not work. I hope you can help me. As seen from the photo, in red there is written "Unknown AVD", but the emulator is there.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fkXr.png)

Comment: It will be helpful if you show an example of what you're doing and/or what you see. Are you getting any error messsge?

Comment: @IvanVerges look up